# tkinter drop down menu from excel

Tags: python, excel, tkinter

I want to use `tkinter` to browse an excel sheet and make a drop down menu of the rows of that excel sheet.
I am pretty new to `python` and do not know how to work it through. The code until now looks like this:

```
import xlrd
import os
from subprocess import call

import Tkinter,tkFileDialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfiles(title='Choose an excel file')
print(filename)
print type(filename)
#file = str(filename)
file = [filetypes for filetypes in filename if ".xlsx" in filetypes]
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
for file in filename:
  sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
  print(sheet)

  for value in sheet.row_values(0):
    print(value)
```

This throws an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Geocoding/test.py", line 14, in 
>       workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
>     File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py", line 394, in open_workbook
>       f = open(filename, "rb")
>   TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

I am not even able to read the excel sheet that the user browses. I have no idea why this error. I would really appreciate if anybody can help me with it. Am I on the right path ?

Thanks

The new code that works:
    import xlrd
    from Tkinter import *

```
import Tkinter,tkFileDialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title='Choose an excel file')
print(filename)
print type(filename)
#file = str(filename)
file = [filetypes for filetypes in filename if ".xlsx" in filetypes]
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
#for file in filename:
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
print(sheet)

for value in sheet.row_values(0):
  print(value)
  print(type(value))

master = Tk()
variable=StringVar(master)
#variable=sheet.row_values(0)[0]
variable.set(sheet.row_values(0)[0])

#for var in value:
# variable = StringVar(master)
# variable.set(value) # default value

#w = OptionMenu(master, variable, value)
w = apply(OptionMenu, (master, variable) + tuple(sheet.row_values(0)))
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: askopenfiles returns a list.  You are assigning filename to a list, rather than to a string.  You probably want the first item in that list

Comment: How do I give the user a chance to open the excel files he wishes and then I have to read the column names and pass those names as drop-down menu inputs?? @VinceWest

Answer (score 0):

You may have more errors along the way but in your code here:

```
filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfiles(title='Choose an excel file')
```

the result from that dialog is a list of file objects.  So you are passing that list of fileobjects to open_workbook here:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
```

Instead what you need to do is pass the name of the file you care about as a string to open_workbook:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename[0].name)  # the name of the first file in the list
```

here is a working Python3 (sorry I abandoned Python2) example for tkinter to properly select filenames:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

filename = filedialog.askopenfiles(title='Choose an excel file')

print(filename)  # filename is a list of file objects
print(filename[0].name)  # this is the name of the first selected in the dialog that you can pass to xlrd
```

Comment: Hi @Vince I was able to do that part. I want to select a value from the drop down and replace it using a text input. Here is my new code. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.